What does \mathitalicsmode actually do in LuaTeX?
While researching the way LuaTeX handles italic corrections, I’ve seen various mentions of \mathitalicsmode. Unfortunately, the section of the manual describing its behavior has not helped me very much. It says:

The \mathitalicsmode parameter can be set to 1 to force italic correction before noads that represent some more complex structure (read: everything that is not an ord, bin, rel, open, close, punct or inner). A value of 2 will enforce the old school font code path for all italics.

The explanation of what happens when \mathitalicsmode is 1 makes sense to me, I think. However, I am still left with two questions:

What is the default behavior when \mathitalicsmode is (presumably) 0? It doesn’t sound like it’s the way plain TeX does things, since that’s what I assume the value of 2 means. But in that case, what does it do?

What exactly does “enforce the old school font code path” mean? Is it something that is useful with old fonts but counterproductive with new fonts? If so, how/why?


The manual contains the following illustration, which is supposed to highlight the difference between modes 0 and 1 using Cambria Math:

It’s possible that I’m simply insufficiently discerning, but both illustrations look absolutely identical to me, which does not help to clarify matters. Can someone who knows more than I do explain what I’m missing?

It's quite difficult to see in the picture from the manual, but the last example with $T\sqrt{1}$ actually shows the difference.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\tracingonline=1

\begin{document}

\mathitalicsmode=0
\sbox0{$T\sqrt{1}$}\showbox0

\mathitalicsmode=1
\sbox0{$T\sqrt{1}$}\showbox0

\mathitalicsmode=2
\sbox0{$T\sqrt{1}$}\showbox0

\stop

First case (parameter set to 0)
> \box0=
\hbox(9.18+1.22)x19.17, direction TLT
.\mathon
.\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 
.\hbox(9.18+1.22)x13.33, direction TLT
..\hbox(0.4+9.6)x8.33, shifted -8.38, direction TLT
...\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 √
..\vbox(9.18+0.0)x5.0, direction TLT
...\kern0.4 (font)
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
...\kern1.72 (font)
...\hbox(6.66+0.0)x5.0, direction TLT
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 1
.\mathoff

Second case (parameter set to 1)
> \box0=
\hbox(9.18+1.22)x20.65, direction TLT
.\mathon
.\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 
.\kern1.48 (italic)
.\hbox(9.18+1.22)x13.33, direction TLT
..\hbox(0.4+9.6)x8.33, shifted -8.38, direction TLT
...\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 √
..\vbox(9.18+0.0)x5.0, direction TLT
...\kern0.4 (font)
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
...\kern1.72 (font)
...\hbox(6.66+0.0)x5.0, direction TLT
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 1
.\mathoff

Third case (parameter set to 2)
> \box0=
\hbox(9.18+1.22)x20.65, direction TLT
.\mathon
.\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 
.\kern1.48 (italic)
.\hbox(9.18+1.22)x13.33, direction TLT
..\hbox(0.4+9.6)x8.33, shifted -8.38, direction TLT
...\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 √
..\vbox(9.18+0.0)x5.0, direction TLT
...\kern0.4 (font)
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
...\kern1.72 (font)
...\hbox(6.66+0.0)x5.0, direction TLT
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 1
.\mathoff

Conclusion
The manual speaks the truth!

Thanks, this does help me see that there is some difference. But I don’t think it fully answers my question: what is the difference between \mathitalicsmode=1 and \mathitalicsmode=2? What does “enforce the old school font code path” mean?

@AlexisKing For instance, do the same with only \sbox0{$T$}; you'll see a difference between 0 or 1 and 2.
